# How to generate requests at a "requests/sec" target rate?

Tags: timer, load-testing

Say I have a target of `x` requests/sec that I want to generate continuously. My goal is to **start** these requests at **roughly the same interval**, rather than just generating x requests and then waiting until 1 second has elapsed and repeating the whole thing over and over again. I'm not making any assumptions about these requests, some might take much longer than others, which is why my scheduler thread will not perform the requests (or wait for them to finish), but hand them over to a sufficiently sized Thread Pool.

Now if `x` is in the range of hundreds or less, I might get by with .net's `Timer`s or `Thread.Sleep` and checking actually elapsed time using `Stopwatch`.

But if I want to go into the thousands or tens of thousands, I could try going high-resolution timer to maintain my *roughly the same interval* approach. But this would (in most programming environments on a general OS) imply some amount of hand-coding with spin waiting and so forth, and I'm not sure it's worthwhile to take this route.

Extending the initial approach, I could instead use a Timer to sleep and do `y` requests on each Timer event, monitor the actual requests per second achieved doing this and fine-tune `y` at runtime. The effect is somewhere in between "put all x requests and wait until 1 second elapsed since start", which I'm trying not to do, and "wait more or less exactly 1/x seconds before starting the next request".

The latter seems like a good compromise, but is there anything that's easier while still spreading the requests somewhat evenly over time? This must have been implemented hundreds of times by different people, but I can't find good references on the issue.

So what's the easiest way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it:

First find (good luck on Windows) or implement a **`usleep`** or **`nanosleep`** function. As a first step, this could be (on .net) a simple `Thread.SpinWait()` / `Stopwatch.Elapsed > x` combo. If you want to get fancier, do `Thread.Sleep()` if the time span is large enough and only do the fine-tuning using `Thread.SpinWait()`.

That done, just take the inverse of the rate and you have the time interval you need to sleep between each event. Your basic loop, which you do on one dedicated thread, then goes

1. Fire event
2. Sleep(sleepTime)

Then every, say, 250ms (or more for faster rates), check the actually achieved rate and adjust the `sleepTime` interval, perhaps with some smoothing to dampen wild temporary swings, like this

```
newRate = max(1, sleepTime / targetRate * actualRate)
sleepTime = 0.3 * sleepTime + 0.7 * newRate
```

This adjusts to what is actually going on in your program and on your system, and makes up for the time spent to invoke the event callback, and whatever the callback is doing on that same thread etc. Without this, you will probably not be able to get high accuracy.

Needless to say, if your rate is so high that you cannot use `Sleep` but always have to spin, **one core will be spinning continuously**. The good news: We get ever more cores on our machines, so one core matters less and less :) More serious though, as you mentioned in the comment, if your program does actual work, your event generator will have less time (and need) to waste cycles.

Check out https://github.com/EugenDueck/EventCannon for a proof of concept implementation in .net. It's implemented roughly as described above and done as a library, so you can embed that in your program if you use .net.

Comment: Will check it out, but maybe you could describe the implementation in your answer rather than just pointing to a library.

Comment: +1 `EventCannon` works with an astonishing accuracy. I tried various values in the range of 500 and 5000 events/sec and it's off by less than 1% consistently. True, for higher rates it will burn CPU cycles, but the rest of my program is obviously doing actual work on every event, so it competes with the cannon for cycles, which means less cycles left for the cannon to burn. Maybe one could lower the priority of the cannon's thread without impacting accuracy? Anyway, if you expand on the description in your answer, I could consider accepting it, unless better alternatives show up.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense, and the implementation works so well that you have to be careful not to set the requests / sec rate too high, otherwise you'll overload the target in no time, because the items start to queue up at an ever growing rate. I guess the name "event cannon" makes sense - it's a dangerous tool, that does not back off, unless you perform your work on the calling thread, which is the one that also fires.